# re.findall from python to Java matches, patterns

Tags: java, python

I wish to convert my re.findall(regex) to java.
I know how to use the match and pattern but I will have to compile it many times when I have multiple regex pattern to find. For example;

```
text = "-3-testing"
text_temp = re.findall("(.?\d+.)",text) # here one time
if len(text_temp) != 0:
    if "-" in text_temp[0]:
        text_temp = re.findall("(\d+.\d+)", text) #here second time
```

above is my python code, but if I wanted to convert to java then it means I will need to compile it 2 times and then match it again with the text and then reextract those matches. I wanted to know whether is there a more shorter way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your question in your question - unless I am missing something.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your regex");
```

Then you can use the methods of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as needed.
You can compile as many patterns as you like and use them to generate as many matchers as you can handle.

For example:

```java
Matcher m = p.matcher("some input");
```

And from there you can use the [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) to do all your extraction of data, stepping through matches, replacements and so on...

As for having multiple patterns, you will need to compile each pattern unless you can combine them IInto one. Perhaps by using the "alternatives" operator "|" or having a more generic (or more specific) pattern. Which gives rise to the question, why would you regex something generic only to constrain it more in another  step?

Perhaps you could do something like this and have just one?

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-(\d+.\d+)");
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to have the compile, matcher, matches(which is used to print all the matched substring) in single line?

Comment: Yes via the various methods defined in [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). But that would almost certainly compile the pattern each time you called it. And your question was about **not** compiling it each time.

Comment: Oh and the easy way to find these methods when looking at the String javadoc is to simply find "regex" in the documentation. All the methods that accept a regex use the value "regex" as their parameter name.